# Whoops on Laravel 5.2 not working

Tags: php, debugging, exception, laravel-5, whoops

Following [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/whoops-20-laravel-52) to use Whoops as debugger,

I'm not able to see chrome page like this:

[image]

but it looks like this no matter what error I get:

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. run `composer require filp/whoops --dev`
2. modify app/Exceptions/Handler.php

`public function render($request, Exception $e) {
    if (config('app.debug') && ! $request->ajax()) {
        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
        return $whoops->handleException($e);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}`

3. modify config/app.php

`'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)`

4. run `php artisan config:clear`

How can I bring Whoops to my Laravel5.2 project?

Comment: Have you checked the `laravel.log` file in `storage/logs`? Or checked the `error.log`?

Comment: There's only some error logs recorded before I made these changes. Do I have to enable any render setting that I might be missing?